# Force user to login before add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I tried the below solution found over google but it doesn't gave me the required output.
I have edited the file as follows,
app/design/frontend/[template]/[package]/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart');

if(Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): 
    if($_product->isSaleable()): 
?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php 
    endif;
else:
?>
    <p><?php echo $this->__('Please <a href="%s">login</a> to buy this product', Mage::getUrl('customer/account'));?></p>
<?php
endif; 
?>
```

Let me know, what I am missing here.

Comment: try `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You will be required to redirect your user to previous page after login. Hence write code for redirect also.

```
<?php
if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
    Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
            ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); 
    echo '<p>Please <a href="'.Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login').'">Login</a> to buy this product.</p>';
}

else
{
 put here your desired add to cart code.
}
?>
```

I hope this code will help you.